# Error: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "origin", intValue: nil),

Tags: ios, json, swift

### **This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear

I am building a small swift dog fetch app using the DogsApi and I am running into some issues trying to parse the JSON. I have used the following function to parse the get and parse the JSON.

Below is my  viewController:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    

    var dogs = [DogStats]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        downloadJson {
            print("Successful")
        }
    }
    
    func downloadJson(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DevTides/DogsApi/master/dogs.json") {
           URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
              if let data = data {
                 do {
                    let dogs = try JSONDecoder().decode([DogStats].self, from: data)
                    print(dogs)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self.dogs   = dogs
                       self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                 } catch let error {
                   print(error)
                 }
              }
           }.resume()
        
    }
    }

}
```

**below is my struct**

```
import Foundation

struct DogStats:  Codable {
    let name: String
    let origin: String
    let breed_group: String!
    let life_span: String
    let temperament: String
}
```

**Error in debugger**

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "origin", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 5", intValue: 5)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "origin", intValue: nil) ("origin").", underlyingError: nil))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

origin, breed_group, temperament are not contained in all of your JSON objects in your API data. So there parse error occurred. You can make those optional(i.e. let origin: String?). You can also make all of your fields optional.

```
struct DogStats:  Codable {
    let name: String
    let origin: String?
    let breed_group: String?
    let life_span: String
    let temperament: String?
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I deeply appreciate